# Why does strictly decreasing or strictly increasing function affect calculating derived distribution?

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why whether a function being strictly increasing or decreasing changes the equality for $F_Y(y)$? Also how would you deal with neither strictly increasing or decreasing function, cause that would mean it's not invertible, which I'm not sure how it affects getting the derived distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case we have ($v$ is an increasing function: $x\le y \implies v(x) \le v(y)$)
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \le y) \\ &= P(v(Y) \le v(y)),
\end{align}
while in the second case we have ($v$ is a decreasing function: $x\le y \implies v(x) \ge v(y)$)
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y \le y) \\ &= P(v(Y) \ge v(y)),
\end{align}
hence the equality for $F_Y(y)$ does not change. For the second question, you just need the transformation to be measurable (weaker condition than invertible), and you could have a look, for example, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174161/let-x-be-a-random-variable-and-f-an-invertible-function-then-the-cdf-of-a-r).